# Java - Error in eclipse: the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a small part of my code. My project is to simulate a whole school system. To add teachers, courses etc. All of my class members are private, so i created setters and getters methods. I try to give to 'teachersNum' a value and this must be automatic(not from keyboard). So i want to give it value 1 if its the first teacher etc. I hope you can understand. Sorry for my English.

```
public void addTeachersList(Teachers teachers) {
   if(this.teachersSize<100){
     this.teachersList[this.teachersSize] = teachers;
     this.teachersList[this.teachersSize].getTeacherNum() = this.teachersSize -1;
     this.teachersSize++;
   }
}
```

Comment: At which line it gives an error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to call a setter:

```
this.teachersList[this.teachersSize].setTeacherNum(this.teachersSize-1);
```

Calling the getter getTeacherNum just gives you the number, it isn't a reference to that property.

Although I must say, you'd really do yourself a favor by using a `List` implementation instead of arrays.

Comment: Not to mention naming the method addTeachersList() is a bit misleading.

Comment: I used arrays because of i come from c and i am now learning java. I used also a setter and i saw that when i print the results teacherNum is always in 0.

Comment: If it's always zero, it's not because there's something wrong with calling a setter, but because you either print the wrong thing or the setter is not implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
this.teachersList[this.teachersSize].getTeacherNum() = this.teachersSize -1;
```

`getTeacherNum()` returns a value. You can't assign to it.

Comment: ok thank you. I think I understood the use of getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem here

```
this.teachersList[this.teachersSize].getTeacherNum() = this.teachersSize -1;
```

.getTeacherNum() will return a value which must be stored in a variable on left side.

eg:

temp = .getTeacherNum();

And its better to use a static variable to keep the count of teachers, so every time a teacher is created he/she gets a nos which is different from the previous one

eg:

```
 xxxx001
 xxxx002
 xxxx003
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean? I think that with my method every teacher gets a different number .
1
2

Comment: getTeacherNum() will return a value, as its a getter method...now u need to store that value in a variable.

Comment: Its just my way of doing it.... there may be hundred others... When i need to make some unique id... for eg: Student class, ever student object has its own instance variable, but ever object will have only one static variable to share among them, so i can use this to give unique id, to them.. for example keep incrementing it by some nos, and store in objects instance varible like id..etc

Comment: and did my answer helped u regarding your question ??

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem here

```
this.teachersList[this.teachersSize].getTeacherNum() = this.teachersSize -1;
```

`.getTeacherNum()` will return a value which must be stored in a variable on left side.

eg: `temp = .getTeacherNum()`;

And its better to use a static variable to keep the count of teachers, so every time a teacher is created he/she gets a nos which is different from the previous one

eg:

```
xxxx001
xxxx002
xxxx003
```